# Where were the user before landing in my web site?

Tags: php

I would like know where the user where were before landing in my web site.
Is there any php function to do that?

I tried `$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but i only get the link of my website.

[I would like something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8e3W.png)

I tried to post the link of my website on fb and if i check the `$referer` of that one i keep getting my website link

Comment: _Where were*_... . I found a couple duplicates ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6795128/4577762), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2313834/4577762)) that say this is what you need. Can you elaborate a bit more on the **why** that didn't help you?

Comment: What you want is not possible unless you participate in super-cookies.

Comment: `$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is only good if a website links to your site and the user's web browser respects and sets this value.

Comment: _“but i only get the link of my website”_ – if the user reached the current page via a link on a previous page of your site – then that _is_ where they “were before.”

Comment: Why are you so nosey?