# check if user didnt come from url

Tags: php

How do I check in PHP if a user **didn't** come from a certain URL and redirect them?

For example, if they came from hello.php, nothing would happen, but if they came from any other page, they would be redirected?

Comment: Something like this? `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://example.com/hello.php") { header("Location: index.php"); }` Not entirely bug-free (because you can come from a page with or without `www`), but gives you a general idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313834/how-to-detect-the-site-a-user-came-from-before-mine-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value to determine where the user came from:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match('/hello\.php$/', $referer) === 1) {
    echo 'Came from hello.php';
} else {
    echo 'Did not come from hello.php';
}
```

You should be careful, however. The `HTTP_REFERER` header value can be changed by the client. In other words, never assume that it is correct.

Comment: Is there a solution which cannot be changed by the client?

Comment: @johndoe23 no if the 'from' page is not controlled by you, yes if it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( strpos( $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] , 'hello.php') === false ) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit;
}
```

But, some browsers cuts this referer param

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to this, in PHP your best shot would be to use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],

```
$previous_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

But this variable would not always be set, as some servers might set it to null, it cannot be completely relied upon.

Other choice you have is to use Javascript, this is a more reliable method than the HTTP_REFERER,

```
var previous_url = document.referrer;
```